# Stuck on SQL assignment

Tags: sql

**The question**

> Which customers placed orders at store number 1 in the 4th quarter of 1995? 
>   Display the customer id, first and last name, city and state.  List in ascending customer id order.

**What I have so far**

```
SELECT person.id, person.firstname, person.lastname, person.city, person.state
FROM person
INNER JOIN Order_header
ON person.id=order_header.customer_id
WHERE store_number = 1 
ORDER BY customer_id asc
```

**Where I am stuck**
The 4th quarter of 1995 part, and how I integrate it with what I already have.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, I freely admit I have no idea what I am doing.

Tables.

---

person

```
    [id]
   ,[lastname]
   ,[firstname]
   ,[mi]
   ,[street]
   ,[city]
   ,[state]
   ,[zip]
   ,[area_code]
   ,[phone_number]
```

order_header

```
   [invoice_number]
  ,[store_number]
  ,[customer_id]
  ,[account_number]
  ,[order_date]
  ,[est_delivery_date]
  ,[delivery_date]
  ,[amount_due]
```

Comment: You'll need post more details, like your table structure

Comment: Also is it a fiscal quarter or calendar year quarter?  so are you only interested in those whose date is between Oct 1st 1995 and 11:59:59 of December 31st?

Comment: I was wondering myself but all I have to go on is the question and it just says the 4th quarter of 95.

Comment: Without any other qualification, it must be calendar quarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices:

(1) In your `WHERE` clause, include something like

```
AND '1995-10-01' <= order_header.order_date AND order_header.order_date < '1996-01-01'
```

(2) This second option is simpler, but it will only work if the date is just the plain date (no time), e.g. *not* `1995-12-31 05:30:10`:

```
AND order_header.order_date BETWEEN '1995-10-01' AND '1995-12-31'
```

Of course, I'm assuming something like `order_header.order_date` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
select person.id, person.firstname, person.lastname, person.city, person.state 
from person
inner join order_header on person.id = order_header.customer_id
where order_header.store_number = 1 and order_header.order_date between '10-1-1995' and '1-1-1996'
order by order_header.customer_id desc
```

Comment: This will not work; it will include records whee `order_header.order_date` is `1996-01-01`. And is the date format that you used standard?

Comment: 1996-1-1 at midnight, which is a 1 second overlap. Versus your solution, which includes all of September... Also, he didn't specify which version of SQL he is using so the best any of us can do is get close to an answer and let him figure out the rest.

Comment: Unless it is a date, not datetime field, in which case it is a whole day. Your insight on my answer is appreciated; I edited it accordingly.

Comment: Same with you! Take care and happy coding.